# Do suggested edit rejections count against me?

Tags: discussion

Basically what the question says, if my suggestion was rejected cause of a subsequent edit does this rejection counts against me as an editor?

Answer (score 4):

No, rejections due to edit conflict do not count against you.

> We now ignore any suggested edits that were rejected by the Community User due to an edit conflict when determining whether someone should be banned from submitting suggested edits.

From [Suggested edit rejections for concurrent edits should not count for the suggested edit ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983)